# Using IF function to designate two values into 1 group

Tags: java, if-statement, jasper-reports

When using `IF` function to make two values as one group it returns error where am i went wrong? The function is as below

`IF("Class Code"=='U' AND 'P', 'Productive')` I tried this also not working
`IF("Class Code"=='U' OR 'P', 'Productive')`

It works if using only one value like so

`IF("Class code"=='U', 'Productive')`

Would someone be so kind to advise?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b2gX.jpg)

Comment: It would help if you also mentioned what language you're talking about. Excel formulas?

Comment: I don't recognize the language, but at least as far as I know you normally need the complete comparison statement after "or". So in your case I would try IF("Class Code"=='U' OR "Class Code" == 'P', 'Productive')

Comment: So... you're not going to tell what the language is? Is it a secret?

Comment: @juhana its jaspersoft see the error image its using java i think sorry to skip your question. I appreciate you trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recognize the language, but at least as far as I know you normally need the complete comparison statement after "or". So in your case I would try `IF("Class Code"=='U' OR "Class Code" == 'P', 'Productive')`